# Strange PineScript scope function call behaviour

Tags: pine-script

The following code has a very strange behaviour causing me a major headache:

```
//@version=5
indicator("GM Multi Debug", overlay = true, precision = 4)

IndexSeries = request.security('TVC:DJI', timeframe.period, close)

// func: Returns the difference between the current IndexSeries value and the lowest IndexSeries 
// value in the last n bars.

func(n) =>
    IndexSeries[0] - ta.lowest(IndexSeries, n + 1)

// Test Values
int k = 6
float TestVar = 0.0 // Stores the result of func(n) assigned in local scope.
int TestVar2 = 0    // Stores an int value to check whether the if statement condition is true or not.

if func(k) >= 18
    TestVar := func(k) // Assign the return value of func to TestVar.
    TestVar2 := +1 // Assign int value to verify that the body of the if-statement was executed.

// TestVar := func(k)

// DIAGNOSTICS
plot(func(k) >= 18?1:0, color=color.purple, title = 'func(k) >= 18?')
plot(func(k)                   , title = "func(k)",   color = color.green)
plot(TestVar                    , title = "TestVar",   color = color.gray)
plot(TestVar2                    , title = "TestVar2",   color = color.gray)
```

As can be seen in the following image TestVar (which is essentially the value of func(6) called in a local scope) has the value 30121.2400 while func(6) called in a global scope has the value 19.75. This can be confirmed by uncommenting "// TestVar := func(k)", which would fix the issue seen in the image and correcting the value of TestVar to 19.75.

[image: Image displaying the same function return value being different.]

I would just like to understand why this happens and if there is a solution that isn't just assigning the return value of the function in a global scope, because in some situations (eg. iterative calculations) it is extremely impractical.

Answer (score 0):

Some function calls is separate functional objects with its own state. For correct calculations those functions must be called on every bar (once). This is true for `ta.lowest` too (and custom functions that calls `ta.lowest`).
The Pine compiler warns you about this:

> line 18: The function 'func' should be called on each calculation for
> consistency. It is recommended to extract the call from this scope.